# Conditional Distribution over the unit disc

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

How can I show that, $U$ and $V$, two independent uniform $(-1,1)$ random variables have a conditional distribution, given that $U^2 + V^2 <1$, that takes the form:

$$f_{U,V|U^2+V^2<1} (u,v|w<1) =1/{\pi}, \quad u^2+v^2<1$$

I tried using the CDF technique for $W=U^2+V^2$

$$ \frac{P\left[ U^2+V^2 \leq w , U^2+V^2 <1 \right]}{P \left[ U^2+V^2<1 \right]}=P \frac{\left[ U^2+V^2 \leq w \right]}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

because the event $[U^2+V^2 \leq w] \subset [U^2+V^2<1] $

But after that, I am stuck as even if I was to evaluate the double integral at the numerator, it does not seem that I would get the required distribution. Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: One approach: what is the probability of being in an element $(u,u+du)\times (v,v+dv)$ before the restriction to the circle? What is the conditional probability of being in the element, given you're in the circle?

Comment: Hint: to evaluate $P\{U^2+V^2 \leq w\}$ switch to _polar_ coordinates.  But give some thought to the _uniform_ distribution and think of ways of computing this probability without the formality of integration.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Indeed, the second half of your comment was what I was getting at in my comment.

Comment: @Glen_b I understand your point but what about the joint probability of being in the element and in the circle at the same time?  Is it just $1/4 \times 1 $?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I cannot get integration to work unfortnately. Taking the bounts as $(0,\sqrt{w}) \times (0,2\pi) $ and after differentiating wrt to $w$, I am left with simply $1/4 \pi $, not the $1/4$ we were looking for.

Comment: If $(u,v)$ is in the circle, you take the element to be in the circle.

Comment: Check your integration! What happened to the $2\pi$ coming out of $\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate  The numerator is $$ \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{w}} \frac{1}{4} r drd\theta $$ which gives $(1/4) w \pi$ and upon differentiation $(1/4) \pi$ and when you divide that with the den. you get simply 1. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are needing the (conditional) _joint_ pdf of $U$ and $V$ given that $U^2+V^2 < 1$. Why on earth are you trying to compute the CDF of $W = U^2+V^2$ since that is totally irrelevant to the issue?

Comment: Didn't you read my OP? I tried using the CDF technique in order to derive that distribution. What was the integration you were proposing?

Comment: Yes, I read your proposed method.  It gives the result that conditioned on $U^2+V^2 < 1$, $W = U^2+V^2$ is _uniformly distributed_ on $[0,1]$, and so the conditional pdf of $W$ has value $1$ (as you correctly computed) on $[0,1]$. You have not gone wrong in the _computation_ that you did, only in the _interpretation_ of the result. What I am trying to point out to you but you choose to ignore is that the distribution of $W$ is not going to be directly useful in determining the _joint pdf_ of $U$ and $V$ which is what you are trying to find.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes I sometimes misunderstand concepts, being a beginner does that but I do not ignore on purpose anyone who is trying to help . Now, the joint pdf is easy to find considering the independence of the RVs. It is why the quotient takes that very form that had been puzzling me and to that end Glen's comment was helpful.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are independent, but they are **conditionally dependent** given that $U^2+V^2 < 1$, and so you cannot use the independence of $U$ and $V$ after you have assumed that $U^2+V^2 < 1$; in this case, knowing the value of $U$ is $\alpha$ _does_ constrain the value of $V$ to be between $-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$ and $\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$ $\Rightarrow$ dependence!

Comment: Yes of course. I was merely referring to the numerator of your fraction, $f_{U,V} (u,v)=1/4 $, the joint density. In general $P(A,B)=P(A) \times P(B|A) $ but now given that $U^2+V^2 <1 $, i.e. they lie in the unit circle, the second probability $P(B|A)$ is 1. That was the biggest part of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the conditional pdf of $X$ given that $X \leq a$ is just
$$f_{X \mid \{X \leq a\}}(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{f_{X}(x)}{P\{X \leq a\}}, & x \leq a,\\0, &x > a,\end{cases}$$
that is, it is just the pdf of $X$ *scaled* to have total area $1$ (as all
pdfs must have) in the region of the conditioning event, and $0$ in the
complementary event.  The same applies to conditional joint pdfs.  Because
of the uniform distribution, the
probability that the random point $(U,V)$ is in the unit disc is just the ratio
of the area $\pi$ of the disc to that of the square ($4$), and the conditional
joint pdf thus has value
$$\frac{f_{U,V}(u,v)}{P\{U^2+V^2 < 1\}}
= \frac{1/4}{\pi/4} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$ 
in the interior of
the unit disc and $0$ outside.  Put another way, $(U,V)$ is conditionally
distributed uniformly on the unit disc given that $U^2+V^2 < 1$.

Comment: Sorry, visiting this post after a long time! However, still the computation of the conditional joint density doesn't seem rigorous.

Comment: @Ashok Unfortunately, I do not have time to edit my answer to make it as rigorous as you desire. However, since my answer does not meet your standards for rigor, you have the option of posting your own answer that meets your standards. If you wish, your answer can point out the shortcomings of my answer, and perhaps the OP will choose to switch his acceptance of my answer to an acceptance of your answer.